# Want to add new label in new post

Tags: custom-post-types, title

I have 3 different custom post types (news, job, result ,)
When I post something new under any of them, I want   "new" label or gif  for a limited time in title . 
Am already try that one which am found in old ans...
But not working for me

```
add_filter( 'post_class', function( $classes ) 
{
    if ( is_singular() )
        return $classes;

    // now minus last mod time in seconds
    $diff = time() - mysql2date( 'U', $post->post_date );

    if ( DAY_IN_SECONDS <= $diff ) $classes[] = 'new-post';
        return $classes;
});
```

Css

```
.new-post {
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-image: url(new.png) left top no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE, what did you try already, can we have some code with which we may or may not be able to help.

Comment: I try one old answer from here .  But that one not work for me am simply want to add 'new' label after custom post title. I don't know how to do that . Am beginner in php

Comment: Am tried that one

Comment: add_filter( 'post_class', function( $classes ) {

    if ( is_singular() )
        return $classes;

    // now minus last mod time in seconds
    $diff = time() - mysql2date( 'U', $post->post_date );

    if ( DAY_IN_SECONDS <= $diff )
        $classes[] = 'new-post';

    return $classes;
});

Comment: The `post_class` hook applies to the currently viewed item. So, it would affect single posts. But your first conditional says that if the current item is singular (which it always is because of the hook you've chosen) it should simply return the existing classes without modifying them. Your first step is to identify where you want the new label to appear, and then find the right hook or template file to target that location.

Comment: I have website sarkarijobdekho. com am simply want to add label in new post only for 24 hour in post list

Comment: Above code is not mine am find that one from another post